# CSS Footer align one line left and the other right with content higher on page

Tags: html, css, formatting, footer

I have a container div and inside this div is random content and a footer tag. The footer contains 2 spans with random text. I want to align the first span to the left and the second span to the right.

The issue is that my footer is located at the bottom of the window. Because of this the width of the footer is only as wide as the text within it and not of the "containing" block (it is not really the container as apparently CSS considers the container to be the first block to provide a non default position).

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="randomContent">
        <h1>Content of an arbitrarily long length will go here</h1>

        <footer>
            <span class="alignLeft">Hello world</span>
            <span class="alignRight">other text</span>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    display: inline-block;

    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;           /* Height of the footer */
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.alignLeft {
    float: left;

}

.alignRight {
    float: right;

}
```

My [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JSparadoX/xrksofu7/) shows the issue. I want the boxes to be the same width, the "hello world" text to be left aligned and the "other text" to be right aligned in the footer. This should adjust as the "top" text size changes.

Here is a second [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JSparadoX/2owLg3zw/) that shows what I'm looking for. I'm hoping to do this without the java script. The hope is to do this with CSS only.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Is there a reason the footer is being positioned as absolute?  If you change the footer from `position:absolute;` to `position:relative;` and then set the footer `width: 100%;` you might get what you are looking for.  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrksofu7/32/)

Comment: The reason I use `position:absolute;` is so the footer is at the bottom of the page. If I use `position:relative;` the alignment does work but my footer is at the bottom of the content and not the page.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, try this, it worked for me.

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  /* Height of the footer */
  width: 100%;
}
.footer {
  margin: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 50px;
}
.alignLeft {
  float: left;
}
.alignRight {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="randomContent">
    <h1>Content of an arbitrarily long length will go here</h1>

    <footer>
      <div class="footer">
        <span class="alignLeft">Hello world</span>
        <span class="alignRight">other text</span>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you look at the fiddle and expand the width wide enough the .randomContent is not 100% width.  Because the content is not 100% this answer wont work as it doesn't address the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
<style>
            #container {
              display: inline-block;
              border: 1px solid #000000;
              width: auto;
            }
            footer {
              position: absolute;
              bottom: 0;
              left: 0px;
              height: 60px;
              /* Height of the footer */
              width: 100%;
            }
            .footer {
              margin: 8px;
              border: 1px solid #000000;
              height: 50px;
        clear:both;
            }
            .alignLeft {
              float: left;
        min-width:50%;
        width:auto;
        background-color :green;

            }
            .alignRight {
            text-align:right;
              float: right;
        min-width:50%;
        width:auto;
        background-color: red;
            }

     </style>



    <div id="container">
          <div class="randomContent">
            <h1>Content of an arbitrarily long length will go here</h1>

            <footer>
              <div class="footer">
                <span class="alignLeft">Hello world</span>
                <span class="alignRight">other text</span>
              </div>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This does not quite work. I'm looking for the "other text" to be right aligned with the edge of the `#container` div. in the above solution, it is less wide than the `#container` div. If I remove the `min-width:49%;` it is then to wide.

Comment: I have been playing around with your solution. It is definitely closer to what I'm looking for. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JSparadoX/2owLg3zw/). This is the behavior I am looking for. It may not be possible with pure CSS though...

Comment: I thought the latest update was the solution. Unfortunately, the width of the #container was set to 100%. What I want is the width of the container to only be as wide as the arbitrarily long content. I then want the footer to be the same width and have the alignment characteristics previously mentioned. Take a look at my JSFiddle that has the javascript. You will notice that no matter the size of the #container the footer is the same size and the text is correctly aligned. The more I look at this the less I believe it can be solved while only using CSS. I appreciate your persistence!

Comment: Please check now I set the width to auto

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I have found is to use jquery to force the footer to be the same size as its container.

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JSparadoX/2owLg3zw/) for an example

**JavaScript Code**

```
var containerObj = $("#container");
var footerObj = $("footer");

//Event function that resizes the footer to match the container
function matchContainerSize() { 
    var containerWidth = containerObj.width();
    footerObj.css('width', containerWidth);

    console.log("event fired!");
}

//Wire up the event.
$(window).on('resize', matchContainerSize);

//Call the function so that the initial sizing can take place.
matchContainerSize();
```